# Visual Basic Iterative enabling of Textbox's

Tags: vb.net, iteration

Si I'm working on an assignment where I have 10 RadioButtons indicating how many contesters I have, and depending on what I pick between 1 to 10, I need that many of my corresponding TextBoxes to be enabled so I could fill it with names!

Is there a way for me to make a For loop between 1 and the number I picked from the RadioButton and say something like

```
For i = 0 to Size
{
    TextBox&i.Enabled = True
}
```

Since my TextBoxs are called TextBox1 to TextBox10

I know you can add strings together using &, but how can I do that for an object name?

As of right now I literally have the dumbest way of doing it, which is a click event inside each RadioButton that manually enables the correct number of TextBoxes...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all controls like this:

```
For Each ctr In Me.Controls
Dim indx As String = ctr.Name
If TypeOf (ctr) Is Textbox Then
 ' Now compare the name with TextBox&i and do smth
End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems to be the way to do it, using controls

Comment: Keep in mind that the order *may* not be logically consistent with the placement of the controls on the form.  If you have that problem, you can make your own `List(of Checkbox)`, add the checkboxes to that list in the order you need, and loop over that collection instead of `Controls` of the `Form`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to just concatenate a string and use it as an object variable reference like that, but you can search the form's controls by their name property (which is a string) and do it that way. Here's an example:

```
Private Sub EnableTextBoxes(ByVal Size As Integer)
    For i As Integer = 1 To Size
        Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find("Textbox" & i.ToString, True)
        If matches IsNot Nothing AndAlso matches.Length = 1 Then matches(0).Enabled = True
    Next
End Sub
```